# Unable to Use PHP 7.1 and MongoDB 1.3.4 connected through an Nginx Server.

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, nginx

This is the first Question I have ever Asked so I hope I have followed all the norms.

I am trying to create a web server through nginx and work with MongoDB in it via PHP.
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my server.
I installed MongoDb with php as guided through in the below link.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

I dont think so there is something wrong with my installation as :-

I checked phpinfo() and it is succesfully showing mongo in it.

I am able to work with PHP through my nginx 
I am able to code Mongo in the mongo shell.

When I use MongoDB/Driver/Manager it is working for me very well. In fact all the classes in the below link I am able to get the result.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php

However when I run the following code it throws an error 500.

```
$insertOneResult = $db->inventory->insertOne([
   'item' => 'canvas',
   'qty' => 100,
   'tags' => ['cotton'],
   'size' => ['h' => 28, 'w' => 35.5, 'uom' => 'cm'],
]);
```

I have installed PHP 7.1 and PHP--Mongo DB Driver 1.3.4.

I checked in the below link regarding Mongo driver PHP compatibility and I found out that PHP 7.1 is compatible only with Mongo 1.2 and 1.1. Looking at it I downloaded PHP Mongo Driver 1.2 but was not able to after it the mongo vanished from my phpinfo() .

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-mongodb-php

I have exhausted all the resources available to me. So please help me....

Comment: And what do the logs say?

Comment: Well, I checked the error logs and I have successfully diagnosed all the compile time errors and still it is not working...